# onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, browser-history

This code works fine in FF, it takes the user back to the previous page, but not in Chrome:

```
<a href="www.mypage.com" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)">Link</a>
```

What's the fix?

Comment: javascript protocol is not needed

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You should use `window.history` and return a false so that the `href` is not navigated by the browser ( the default behavior ).

```
<a href="www.mypage.com" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"> Link </a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i used history.back(); which in chrome made some nasty bugs :)

Comment: Why create a link to a page (`www.mypage.com`) only to override it with an on-click event and do something other than redirecting the user to that page?

Answer (score 10):

Use the below one, it's way better than the `history.go(-1)`.

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href = document.referrer; return false;"> Go TO Previous Page</a>
```

Comment: It also worked for me, but it won't if the user accesses the page directly.

Comment: If You're sending back to a form, history.go(-1) is a definite better because it returns to the form with most fields with the info they contained before submit

Comment: What you are saying is a valid point but if it was not working that's why this solution was proposed and of course, if we want to go back doesn't really mean that we also need the data we entered into the form, once we have submitted it it can be used with browsers automatically nonetheless. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 8):

Why not get rid of the inline javascript and do something like this instead?

Inline javascript is considered bad practice as it is outdated.

> Notes
>
> Why use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)?
>
> addEventListener is the way to register an event listener as specified
>   in W3C DOM. Its benefits are as follows:
>
> It allows adding more than a single handler for an event. This is
>   particularly useful for DHTML libraries or Mozilla extensions that
>   need to work well even if other libraries/extensions are used. It
>   gives you finer-grained control of the phase when the listener gets
>   activated (capturing vs. bubbling) It works on any DOM element, not
>   just HTML elements.

```
<a id="back" href="www.mypage.com"> Link </a>

document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", window.history.back, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gVf5X/)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<a href="www.mypage.com" onclick="history.go(-1); return false;"> Link </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back 2 Pages</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.go(-2);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:history.go(-1);`

> was used in the **older browser.IE6**. For other browser compatibility try

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

> where -1 represent the number of pages you want to go back (-1,-2...etc) and
>   `return false` is required to prevent default event.

For example :

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;"> Link </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. No problems on using ***`javascript:history.go(-1)`*** on *Google Chrome*.

1. To use it, ensure that you should have history on that tab.
2. Add `javascript:history.go(-1)` on the **enter URL** space.
3. It shall work for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use Simply this line code, there is no need to put anything in href attribute:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.history.go(-1)"> Go TO Previous Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a link with a URL to one page and having an on-click event that overrides it is not a good idea. What if the user opens the link in a new tab?

Consider:

```html
<button id="back">Go back</button>
<script>
document.querySelector("#back").addEvenetListener("click", e => {
    history.go(-1);
});
</script>
```

Or if you must use a link, at least:

```html
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Go back</a>
```